# How to find jquery or javascript event occure from which file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/file1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/file2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/file3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/file4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/file5.js"></script>
```

i have 100 or more js file alert message comes from anywhere how can i hide and find ?

Comment: did not understand your question.

Comment: In file3.js code : alert(3333);  suppose  i run this page alert message will come. that's what i'm asking this alert message come from file3.js how to find this ? when i gonna hide this how to find, suppose i have more than 100 js file how to do ?

Comment: i have 100 or more js file alert message comes from anywhere how can i hide and find ?

Comment: @SelVaa I think it is not possible using any techniques. you have to manually find it.

Comment: @SelVaa  can you please explain what is the need to do so.. you simply want to find thats it..?

Comment: @TintuCRaju  Right now i don't need but i have doubt, any way are there to find event come from which file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a direct method is not available. A possible way is to use inspection tools or any event 
visualization plugins.

In your case you can use current page name on alert messages to identify the pages.

```
    var script_name = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src;
    alert( 'alert message from the file ' + script_name );
```

But i dont think its a good way. I  suggest to use tools like visual event

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

google chrome plugin is also available

http://tinyurl.com/a5hcod2

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have this

File 1:

```
         $(element).bind("click", function(){
              console.dir('button in some file', this);
         });
```

File 2 :

```
           $(element).bind("click", function(){
                console.dir('button in another file', this);
           });
```

if you click and check your console you should have something like this

```
button in some file html elememt .... file1.js:15
button in another file html elememt .... file2.js:20
```

Comment: can you understand what i try to say ?

Comment: No actually your English is a bit weak! but am glad you found your solution.